# Validating records in one table based on data in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This question is an offshoot of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908122/inline-sql-statement-in-access-vba-returning-only-duplicate-first-record-in-reco) here. Using an loop to loop through the recordset based on the Master table, I was able to get all the records returned by my inline Sql statement to show. However, when I actually put the validation code in the loop, valid employees are being reported as invalid and vice versa.

```
Public Function validEmployee(EmpID as String)

Dim Dbs As DAO.database
Dim rs As DAO.recordset
Dim sqlString as String
set dbs = CurrentDb

sqlString = "SELECT [EmployeeID] FROM [MASTER] WHERE [EmployeeStatus] = 'Terminated'"

set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(sqlString)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst // obtain accurate count of records in recordset

If Not (rs.BOF and rs.EOF) Then // Verify recordset is not empty
    Do Until rs.EOF
        If InStr(1, rs.fields("EmployeeID"), EmpID, vbTextCompare) = 0
            validEmployee = "Valid employee"
        Else
            validEmployee = "Employee" & EmpID & "is invalid"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    rs.moveNext
End If
```

Some of the steps I have tried include:

- checking for leading or trailing spaces in field names
- validating the values of EmpID and rs.fields("EmployeeID") via debug.print
- Checking for syntax errors both in SQL and in VBA
- Quotation / escaping of string literals in SQL statement

I feel the problem could be in the way I wrote my InStr() comparison.
Comparison using just a single record without the loop works fine.

Comment: You need to exit the loop once you hit the employee id in question, but why not instead include the employee id in your SQL?  Also, your `MoveNext` needs to be before the `Loop`

Comment: a side note: do they now allow `//` comments in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop over all of the records to find a match: the database can handle that.

```
Public Function validEmployee(EmpID as String)

    Dim rs As DAO.recordset
    Dim sqlString as String

    'add single-quotes around EmpID if it's not a numeric field
    sqlString = "SELECT count([EmployeeID]) as num FROM [MASTER] " & _
                " WHERE [EmployeeStatus] = 'Terminated' and " & _
                " [EmployeeID] = " & EmpID

    set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sqlString)
    validEmployee = rs.Fields("num").Value>0
End If
```